# C++ DLL Class Export, compiler "optimizes" virtual call

Tags: c++, c, dll, dllimport

i am creating a DLL API (MSVC12), and i really want to use a class export.

The problem is: i have a nested class which calls are handled as "direct calls",
i didn't find an elegant way of forcing a virtual table call.

(Note: i trimmed some of the interface for readability)

```cpp
// interface.h
class CEvent {
public:
 virtual bool hasOccured();
}
class ISimulator {
public:
 virtual void Init();
 CEvent initEnded;
}

void DLL_API_INTERFACE ISimulator* GetSimulator();

// interface.c - DLL implementations -> Irrelevant


// CLIENT APP
auto mdl = LoadLibrary(...);
auto getSimFunc = GetProcAddress(mdl, ...);
ISimulator* my_sim = getSimFunc();

m_sim->Init(); // << OK
...
...
m_sim->initEnded.hasOccured() // << LNK: Undefined Reference
```

The obvious solution of making CEvent* instead of CEvent seems pretty awful as it will require heap allocations, and proper destruction which i tend to avoid when possible.

another solution was to make an accessors to `CEvent` that return `CEvent*` and therefore force a vtbl call.

**My Question**: Can i force the compiler to treat `CEvent::hasOccured()` as virtual call ?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with full source code and the full error message. It doesn't look like you're exporting the classes though

Answer (score 2):

The title says "*DLL Class Export*" but there is no class exported in the posted code. It is possible that just changing `class CEvent` to (something like) `class DLL_CLASS_INTERFACE CEvent` might fix the issue, though that's not necessarily the "right" solution.

Another way would be to expose not the `initEnded` object itself, but a `CEvent *` pointer to it, leaving the compiler no choice but to generate a virtual call.

However, if `ISimulator` is meant to look/work like an interface proper, then it should not expose data members to begin with. Instead, you could hide `initEnded` altogether, and add another method to the `ISimulator` interface `virtual bool InitEndedHasOccurred();`.